Finding the set of solution to a linear sums problem
I have a set of fixed prices $P_1, \dots, P_{50}$, and a corresponding set of fixed caps $C_1, \dots, C_{50}$. I also have a limit of $L$. All are positive natural numbers ($1, \dots $).
In addition, I have two distances, $0 \le DL < L$ and $DH \ge 0$.
The problem is finding solutions $S_1, \dots, S_k$, each containing a set of integer weights $w_1, \dots, w_{50}$, where $0 \le w_i \le C_i$, such that $L-DL \le \sum_i w_i P_i \le L + DH$.
Any hints about solving this not using iteration on all possible combinations of $w$?

I encourage you to use Mathjax/Latex to format the mathematics in your question.

Please [edit] your post to specify whether you require weights to be integers or whether you allow them to be real numbers.  Please correct "interaction".

I don't think there is a general efficient algorithm for your problem. If you take DL=DH=0 then your basically have the subset sum problem, which is NP-complete (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).
However, it is very easy to formulate your problem as an integer program (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). A lot of programming languages have libraries with integer programming solvers, that can usually solve these problems quite efficiently, especially if you only have a couple dozen variables.

Thank you. I'll look into the field of Integer Programming and (ChatGP's recommended) Google OR-Tools. However, do these tools apply any "shortcut tricks," or are these just brute-force iterations?

If you follow the link you have been given for "subset sum problem", I think you'll find that brute force is hopeless, whereas integer programming solvers have considerable cleverness built in.

"it is very easy to formulate your problem as an integer program." - As I have no knowledge of Integer Programming, and my math is from 40 years ago, could you help me with this?

Basically, an integer program is a bunch of equations of the form $a^Tx\leq b$ (where $x$ is the vector of unknowns), with the constraint that all of the elements of $x$ have to be integer. They also usually have a linear objective function (e.g. maximize c^Tx), that could be anything if you just want any solution. If you use software to solve it, you need to formulate all your inequalities in that form. The rest depends on what program you use to solve; some software wants you to write the inequalities in one big matrix ($Ax\leq \mathbf{b}$), and some allow you to write single inequalities.

Thank you very much!
